# I want to filter document by putting condition in populate, Instead of this I get populated field as null with full document in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am using Mongoose With node js and i get full document if I put condition in populated match

Currently I am Managing it by putting condition in JavaScript